# Should template functions be static?

Tags: c++

I often declare utility functions in my source files as `static` to have them linked internally. Now I have a header file with lots of template functions (in a named namespace). Should I make them also static to avoid linking errors or do template functions behave differently?

Comment: `inline` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Once instantiated by the compiler the template behaves as a normal function. Thus, if `static` is required in the context of instantiation that's fine.

Comment: To address a problem I had on AIX, I needed to use inline instead of static.  For some reason xlC didn't like static, but inline succeeded in hiding these the template functions from the linker.
`IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V11.1 (5724-X13)
Version: 11.01.0000.0002`
Thanks @Jarod42

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Template functions are implicitly `inline` (note: not their explicit specialization(s)). So you will not have a linker error related to multiple definitions of the same function. Actually `inline` is now mainly perceived as a linker directive, preventing violations of the [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

### Rationale

If you think about it, implicitly disabling ODR violations for function templates makes the most sense.

The compiler does not instantiate a function template when it sees its definition, it is instantiated when it is used: it is only when the function template is used that the compiler knows which arguments to substitute in the template parameters.

In order to be able to instantiate the function, the compiler needs to see the function template **definition** at the call site, so said definition is usually kept in the same header declaring the function template.
Since this is such a common usage, implicitly marking function template as inline save you some typing !

### `static`

Regarding the `static` keyword: when applied to a non-member function, it will give you *internal linkage*: the method will be available only in the compilation unit(s) where it is defined.

Following the usual approach to function template (providing the definition alongside the declaration in the header), making them `static` present little advantage: the function definition should be available in every translation unit that is seeing the function declaration.